# Returning a value from PHP to HTML

Tags: php, html

EDIT: I have two files, one being HTML and the other a PHP Script. I'm making a simple calculator. In my HTML I have a simple form that contains 4 text boxes.
First text box is to have a number.
Second text box is to have the operation to be performed.
Third text box is the second number.
Fourth text box is the answer. 
When user click on a calculate button, the action attribute redirects the HTML to a PHP script that performs all the algorithms. I wanted the PHP script to return the answer back to the fourth text box in my HTML form.

How can I do this?

Here is my code for the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name = "description" content = "This is a home page"/>
<meta name = "author" content = "William Salazar" />
<meta name = "keywords" content = "exercise for home page"/>
<title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Calculator</legend>
        <form action = "calculate.php" method = "post">
            Please type in two numbers and an operation (ex: 2 + 3)<br/>
            <input type = "text" name = "fNum" size = "2"/>
            <input type = "text" name = "op" size = "2"/>
            <input type = "text" name = "sNum" size = "2"/>=
        <input type = "text" name = "ans" size = "2" readonly = "read" value = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ans);?>"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Calculate"/>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for my PHP Script.

```
<?php
function addition()
{

    $sum = (float)$_POST['fNum'] + (float)$_POST['sNum'];
    $_POST['ans'] = (string)$sum;   
    "<form action ='CalculatorForm.php' method = 'post'>"
    "</form>"
}


    switch($_POST['op'])
    {
        case '+':           
            addition();         
        break;
        case '-':
            subtraction();
        break;
        case '*':
            multiplication();
        break;
        case '/':
            division();     
        break;
        case '^':
            power();
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }

?>
```

Of course I haven't finished with the other function. I am initially trying to test out my addition function and if that worked I was to copy and paste the code.

Comment: instead of php, using javascript here is advisable.

Comment: If you use php and don't sanitize your script properly it won't be long till your site hosts adds for mail order brides and websites that give your free emoticons.

Comment: If this is a homework, and you require PHP and simple form submits to do the calculation, then continue, else, use AJAX or JS to do your calculations.

Comment: Most weekends we get this - the students want to go have a lash - but before they post their homework on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Use AJAX to send data from HTML to PHP and back.
Also, you can do all calculations using Javascript.

Comment: I know it can be done with JavaScript. Fairly easy too I think but I wanted to use HTML and PHP. Everything else is simple it's just sending the info back that I have trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a homework question, then continue with your code, else use either AJAX or JAVASCRIPT solution.

Some tips, if you wish to continue with the classic form submit solution:

- use one page for both display and calculation, say `calculator.php`.
- set your form action to the same page, which is `calculator.php` or remove the action to call the same page.
- after submit, do the calculate as you did above, pass the result to `$ans`, since you used this var to render your form.
- Go back here if you still have problems.